# Bluetooth socket connection

Tags: android, sockets, connection, bluetooth

How can i know if a BluetoothSocket is still connected to the endpoint? How can i detect if the socket has been disconnected by the endpoint?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my apps, I keep track of I/O errors. If a successful `read()` takes place, then I reset the counters. If the error counters go up high enough (4-5 is usually a good number) then I consider the connection dead, and proceed to tear it down and re-build it.

The SDK talks about a state change intent, but I'm not clear whether it's referring to a specific connection, or the bluetooth adapter itself [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html):

> Optionally, your application can also
>   listen for the ACTION_STATE_CHANGED
>   broadcast Intent, which the system
>   will broadcast whenever the Bluetooth
>   state has changed. This broadcast
>   contains the extra fields EXTRA_STATE
>   and EXTRA_PREVIOUS_STATE, containing
>   the new and old Bluetooth states,
>   respectively. Possible values for
>   these extra fields are
>   STATE_TURNING_ON, STATE_ON,
>   STATE_TURNING_OFF, and STATE_OFF.
>   Listening for this broadcast can be
>   useful to detect changes made to the
>   Bluetooth state while your app is
>   running.

Comment: hi Brad..it seems there is no other way to get it work :(..I thought that an alternative solution could be..but i didn't get any result till now..thanks for your reply.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. I am surprised too there isn't a better (built-in) way out there of handling it (like a broadcast).